# How to print grayscale 2D matrix to JPanel using Java

Tags: java, swing, matrix

I have 2D matrix.

```
int[][] matrix;
```

Value of matrix are `int` numbers from interval `(X, Y)`.

For example values of `matrix` are on interval `(0, 1000)`.

How to calculate pixel **grayscale** color??

```
 for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
                myJpanel.setRGB(i, j, grayScaleColor);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does your matrix represent?

Comment: @Pickle its game map. Each value represents the altitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume `val`is the value of a cell. and you want  the point to be black when `val==0` and white when `val==1000`.

In RGB, white is `(255,255,255)`, black is `(0,0,0)`. For gray scale, you simply need to the same value for each 3 components. Ex: `(33,33,33)` or `(D4,D4,D4)`. Lets call this value `c` (for color)

Now, your issue become a simple math problem:

- when `val==0`, `c=0`
- when `val==1000`, `c=255`

Basically, you just change the scale of your matrix.
So `c=(int) (val*255.0/1000.0)`

The color you have to put is `new Color(c,c,c)`

**TL;DR**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
        int c=(int) (matrix[i][j]*255.0/1000.0);
        myJpanel.setRGB(i, j, new Color(c,c,c));
    }
}
```

Note this may not work as I don't know what `myJpanel` type is.

**Edit:**

You have to see this as a mathematical problem.
 We can summarize ou problem like that:

```
c = a*val + constant
```

as your grayscale is linear.
Which is exactly the same as

```
c = a*(val + b)
```

Knowing

```
0 = a*(your_min + b)
255 = a*(your_max + b)
```

by developping this math system, you finally get

```
b = -your_min = -1* your_min
a = 255/(your_max + b) = 255/(your_max-your_min)
```

Comment: Thank you for your replye, work nice! `myJPanel` is `JPanel` with method `setRGB` - which set RGB for pixel.

Comment: And what about if min value is 300 and max value is 600? It' same? `int c=(int) (matrix[i][j]*255.0/600.0);`

Comment: I added some explanation

Comment: Thank you for your explanation